# github: commits incorrectly signed off

Tags: git, github

Anytime I open a PR on github I have to resolve this failed check:

```
 "commits incorrectly signed off"
```

I don't understand why. Is there a command to verify the signoff before opening a PR?

Looking at the github output:

```
Commit sha: 5daed5f, Author: gianpaolo, Committer: gianpaolo; The sign-off is missing.
Commit sha: c76c1a1, Author: gianpaolof, Committer: gianpaolof; The sign-off is missing.
Commit sha: 5e7b46f, Author: gianpaolo, Committer: GitHub; The sign-off is missing.
```

Look like there are 3 different committer?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple github accounts?

Comment: no, I have just one. also, usualy I follow github instruction to solve the issue and it works, but not this time                                                                            :git rebase HEAD~15 --signoff
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 'HEAD~15'

Comment: @ChatterOne I think you are right. I updated the question

Comment: If that's the case, check that your commit e-mail address matches with the e-mail address that's linked to your github account (maybe it's just a typo), see https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address

Comment: @ChatterOne Found out that some old commit have a wrong email. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Since my commit history is short and i have not shared work, this is what I did:

1) remove all signed off

```
    git filter-branch --msg-filter "sed /^Signed-off-by:/d"
```

2) git push -f